# How to do the fastest web scraping for 10 million page?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, web-scraping, .net-core, bots

I know asynchronous programming in .net core and i'm using async code like below:

```
    //...
    while(i < 10000000){ 
           var req = HttpWebRequest.Create($"http://www.example.com?p={++i}");
           var resp = await req.GetResponseAsync();
           var reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
           var res = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
           //....
   }
   //...
```

Is it enough?

Comment: I don't know .net, but if you await in each iteration, isn't that just doing a bunch of blocking for each page, eliminating any possible parallelism?

Comment: i dont know parallel programming i am konw only asynchronous programming. @Dave

Comment: That's what asynchronous programming is (or at least one aspect of it).